# Perform actions after authentication

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I would like to perform some actions after the user has been authenticate with [zfcuser](/questions/tagged/zfcuser).

I have found how to perform actions before:

```php
$events->attach('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain', 'authenticate.pre', function($e) use ($startup) { 
  //actions
});
```

but nothing **after the authentication,** I miss a **trigger**, how to find it ?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I don't know if it's the good way but It's working..

I have just changed the **login_redirect_route** to an controller action to perform some useful stuff and **then to redirect** to the user profile.

By the way the trigger was working perfectly @lluisaznar !

Answer (score 3):

There is no post-authentication trigger defined (at least in the ZfcUser version I use). You can find the existing triggers at ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain\prepareForAuthentication()

```
public function prepareForAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    $e = $this->getEvent()
              ->setRequest($request);

    //THE PRE-AUTHENTICATION YOU USE
    $this->getEventManager()->trigger('authenticate.pre', $e);

    //THIS ONE LAUNCHES THE AUTHENTICATION. LOOK AT:
    //ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db\authenticate()
    $result = $this->getEventManager()->trigger('authenticate', $e, function($test) {
        return ($test instanceof Response);
    });

    if ($result->stopped()) {
        if($result->last() instanceof Response) {
            return $result->last();
        } else {
            // throw new Exception('Auth event was stopped without a response.');
        }
    }

    if ($e->getIdentity()) {
        //THIS IS WHERE THE TRIGGER SHOULD BE PLACED
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You could override this class/method and place the trigger in the place commented above.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I don't understand something: how to get ZfcUser\Entity\User because with this new trigger, I get only the ID from the database and in addition I have no state if the user is logged (hasIdentity()). maybe a trigger have to be set in the authenticate function but it's still the same...

Comment: That's true. This function just validate and place the user key in the Storage (session). The place where the user entity is generated is `ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\read()`, where it does `$identity = $this->getMapper()->findById($identity)`. This is called every time an authentication is performed, that is in every page request. In the prepareForAuthentication() you can't get the entity yet. One possibility is do a findById by yourself just before the trigger you've created, and pass the entity to it.

Comment: Ok I don't know if it's the good way but It's working.. I have just changed the _login_redirect_route_ to an controller action to perform some useful stuff and then to redirect to the user profile. By the way the trigger was working perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Wrestled with this one too today, did a small write up about it in case it helps anyone in the future:

http://circlical.com/blog/2013/7/5/capturing-auth-events-with-zfcuser